I think my professor didn't grade me properly. Can you help me? Two questions about propositional logic formalisation
The questions are the following:
(1) Formalize the following sentences into sentences of L1 with as much detail as possible.  Note any difficulties that arise.
(a) We have a chance at convincing the government not to cut higher education, only if we protest in Utrecht on November 14th.
For this one I gave the following dictionary:
P: We have a chance at convincing the government not to cut higher education.
Q: We protest in Utrecht on November 14th.
Formalisation:
not(Q) -> not(P)
But my professor said this is wrong, because it should be P -> Q. However, they are equivalent, right? I was told that it should be formalised as it is written, but do you guys also read this in the question?
(b) It is possible that the minister won’t listen, but we have to try.
For this one, I formalised only as P, where P means the full sentence. Why? “It’s possible that” is not truth-functional. Possibility is not a truth-functional concept; some falsehoods are possible; some falsehoods are impossible. Thus, possibility cannot be analysed in truth-functional logic. Since we are dealing only with propositional logic, we didn't even learn modal logic, it doesn't make sense to me to split in two.
My professor told me it should be P and Q, where P = "It is possible that the minister won’t listen" and Q = "we have to try"! But if we do like that, P does not yield a truth-value, right?
Extra: how can I better approach my professor when dealing with these questions?

We have a chance is translated by not(we have no chance).

@Hudjefa If he says that P->Q and ~Q->~P aren't equivalent, he most certainly is wrong.

How do we get the site runners to enable LaTex for PhilosophySE?

Every basic logic class I've attended when I was a student was crap. This question is a good reminder of that! You clearly have a good understanding of logic that already exceeds the expectations of this class, but your teacher also expects you to read their mind, and your mind-reading abilities are not up to their expectations. Don't waste too much energy into it.

@Stef: "your teacher also expects you to read their mind,", well, or possibly expects students to read the course material. Not having the course material, we can't tell what it says about "only if" ;-)

@SteveJessop If the "course material" is a descent into the teacher's mind, as opposed to actual logic teaching, then I would advise not spending energy on it ;-)

Formalising "only if" as "implies" is not some weird quirk of this professor's whimsy ;-)

@Ray Indeed, and the professor's response leaves me wondering what they think the point of formalizing natural-language sentences is, if only one of two equivalent formalizations is correct.

With the first one, you are correct that P → Q gives the same truth conditions as not-Q → not-P. What both rule out is P and not-Q.
In general, there are many different but logically equivalent ways you could write a sentence. If the object of the exercise is simply to write something in propositional calculus that gives the correct truth conditions then you answer is fine.
In fact, your version seems somewhat more natural. There is an additional subtlety with conditionals that is not captured by the use of the material conditional. Conditionals typically have an implicature that the antecedent is logically, epistemically or chronologically prior to the consequent. Since it is reasonable to assume that the protest may result in the government changing its decision, it makes sense to place Q in the antecedent. But, as I say, that is a subtle point that is most likely not a feature of a simple logic exercise.
With the second example, I think your professor is correct. The operator "it is possible that" is not truth-functional, but if this is an exercise in propositional logic then we must assume that "it is possible that the minister won't listen" is a proposition with a truth value. The minister might listen or they might not. The word 'but' is a conjunction, so in propositional logic it can be represented as 'and'.
Again, there is an additional implicature that 'but' expresses contrast while 'and' does not, but that is unlikely to be a feature of an exercise in propositional logic.

For the first part, I think P → Q is closer to the construction of the english sentence. (I don't know if that was part of the assignment.) !Q → !P would be "If we don't protest in  Utrecht on November 14th, we don't have a chance at convincing the government not to cut higher education"

@AloisChristen: To my ear, the English “A only if B” typically connotes an inferential “from A, infer B” slightly more strongly than “from not B, infer not A”, but a causal connection only in the direction “not B causes not A”, not “A causes B”.  E.g. “I carry an umbrella only if it’s raining” — the main inference suggested is “if you see me with an umbrella, you can assume it’s raining”, but the causation suggested is “if it’s not raining, then I won’t carry an umbrella”.  So in OP’s question, both answers seem very reasonable.

I would go for an approach like this:
a) The connective here is "Only If" - i.e. the sentence is of the form P only if Q, which is to say that P is false if Q is false, and your natural translation to ¬Q -> ¬P is very sensible.
Methodically, however, when we take it down to the truth table, we have four possible situations -

P is true and Q is true.  We protest and we have a chance.
P is false and Q is false.  We don't protest and we don't have a chance.
P is false and Q is true. We protest and we don't have a chance.
P is true and Q is false.  We don't protest and we have a chance.

Statement 4 would obviously contradict with our original assertion, and this is the conventional "logic homework" reading - the other three are consistent with the statement and so the correct reading is ¬P v Q, which is materially equivalent to P -> Q.
Interestingly, however, given the assertoric force of the original statement, there is also a case to be made that statements 2 and 3 also contradict it.  We are not only asserting the conditional, but also that we do have a chance.  Ie, not only does P -> Q, but also P!
So, controversial suggestion, I would propose that the logical L1 form of this assertion is P & Q, if your professor is interested in the methodological approach.  This also matches the Imperative interpretation of the statement - this assertion is telling people to protest, because we have a chance at convincing the government not to cut higher education.
b) You're right that possibility isn't an L1 logical operator, and neither is "but".  However, "but" is grammatically a sentential composition - P but Q is something similar to P & Q.  It's supposed to be in some ways contrastive, that Q is in some sense at odds with P, and yet it is also true even bearing the contrast in mind.
Just because possibility isn't an L1 operator doesn't mean it can't feature in propositions.  When you later go on to look at Modal and Quantifier logics, the logic still allows for compositions like "(For all x, F(x)) & (For some y, ¬F(y))" as being well formed sentences in the language of first order logic.  The propositional connectives can attach to complex things that are themselves not strictly propositional, and that's okay - Propositional logic just has to work with things that resolve down to self-enclosed propositions in some form, even if there is more sentential structure that might require other logical technology to semantically evaluate.

@Bumble quite right! Duly corrected

Just a warning, I'm speaking here about L1 as part of the mathematical study of logic. Philosophers probably have other concerns that influence how L1 is studied, but I studied it as part of a mathematics degree. We were concerned with correct symbol-pushing, and the implications for foundations of mathematics, but not with debating the subtexts of English sentences!
Your professor is teaching you a particular way to formalise English. Two of the rules are that you must formalise "P only if Q" as "P -> Q", and you must formalise "P, but Q" as "P and Q". You must not formalise them using some other logically equivalent sentence of L1, such as "-Q -> -P" for the first or "-(-P or -Q)" for the second.
If you want to formalise English some other way then you can, but it seems not in this class.
I assume that the reason for the must not, is that manipulating sentences into other equivalent sentences is intended as a later step, after formalisation. Therefore it makes sense for the formalisation to be as routine as possible, with (as far as possible) as single "correct" answer. This avoids you needing to prove or appeal to any theorems about logical equivalence at the step of formalising your English sentences into L1.
As for whether your professor has made a wise choice of rules for the formalisation, that is to some extent a matter of pure preference and to some extent a teaching strategy:
I think the fact that "but" in English conveys slightly different information from "and", but/and that this additional information is not captured in typical L1 formalisations, probably is a useful lesson, and should stand. I would say you are incorrect here even though you are "technically correct". "But" conveys information about the reader's or writer's expectations of what might be true, and nothing extra about what actually is true.
Your approach was to treat "P and Q although you might expect not-Q" to be a statement logically unrelated to either "P" or "Q", whereas your professor's approach is to drop the editorial comment and treat it as identical to "P and Q". Therefore "but" formalises to "and", to make explicit that we have here two separate propositions with a connective. Your way leaves us unable to logically relate this statement to other statements involving P or Q, which is pretty bad. Your professor has lost some nuance, you have created a useless formal proposition. A third way, if you want to pursue your technical correctness, might be to formalise as "P and Q and R", where R is "I believe that the reader expects -Q, or might expect it, and wish to emphasise that they must not believe -Q". It's perfectly possible to reason about belief or expectation, including using formal systems where "X believes P" is related to P and to other statements about the entity X. But what are you even going to do with R in your L1 calculus? Are you formalising any other information about emphasis from English sentences? Do you formalise "P" differently from "P, I tells you!", or "P, unfortunately"? Part of the process of formalising these sentences is deciding what you're going to ignore. If Spock would consider it irrelevant human emotion, then just drop it! ;-)
The trouble with these isolated exercises, is that you probably didn't need to do anything with your L1 sentence "P and Q". If you'd had a bunch of other English sentences involving those same propositions, then it would have been much more obvious that you should stipulate "P and Q" on the basis of the English sentence and then use it to draw a conclusion. For example, if you had "if we should try, then we will try", you could deduce "we will try" from your professor's formalisation, but you could not deduce it from yours. If you had "if it's impossible that the minister will listen, we will go directly to the courts", then you have "-P -> something". So the truth or untruth of P: "it is possible that the minister will listen" is meaningful, albeit if it's true that doesn't deduce anything.
"P only if Q" as "P -> Q" is utterly routine. Sure, you might prefer something different, such as "-Q -> -P", or "-(P and -Q)". I expect you could probably teach a different formalisation and achieve the same educational results. It would matter more in a logic where those aren't all equivalent, but then that's such a different case that you'll be revisiting the rules of formalising English anyway.
Finally there is a question of whether the assignment arguably was "unfair", in that perhaps the professor never explicitly stated the formal meanings of "only if" and "but" (and many other English logic-words) in class. If you were expected to figure out for yourself that "but" means "and", then this is a much tougher assignment than if it was mentioned in class or in your reading material, or appears in examples you've been given. I can't say whether this assignment therefore was too tough for the class you're doing: but unless it affects your grade it is far more sensible to accept that this is how this class formalises English, than to try to argue for easier/fairer assignments. Other classes can do it differently - you are not here being taught a universal truth about the English language or about L1.

Additional exercise for the reader. Think of 5 English sentences including the word "almost", and decide whether it can be formalised as "not"! "I'm almost ready to go", "I almost passed Logic 101", "I almost put the bins out", "I almost lost the election", "I almost never need an umbrella".

+1 " Therefore "but" formalises to "and", to make explicit that we have here two separate propositions with a connective." The OP might be interested to know that the interpretation of 'but' and 'and' in a logical sense revolves around the notion of adversative conjunctions, which are one of a number of types of coordinating conjunctions.


(a) We have a chance at convincing the government not to cut higher education, only if we protest in Utrecht on November 14th.
For this one I gave the following dictionary:
P: We have a chance at convincing the government not to cut higher education.
Q: We protest in Utrecht on November 14th.

not(Q) -> not(P)

But my professor said this is wrong, because it should be P -> Q.

Both are equivalent, and both seem wrong to me. (Q->P and !Q->!P) = Q<->P is the obvious correct answer. Because "only if" requires more than a single implication.
Truth table:



protest
chance to convince
true




no
no
yes


no
yes
no


yes
no
no


yes
yes
yes




P <-> Q



Note this changes if you change P or Q, such as "P: the government does not cut higher education", and such details can cause misunderstanding between you and your professor.

(b) It is possible that the minister won’t listen, but we have to try.

For this one, I formalised only as P, where P means the full sentence. Why? “It’s possible that” is not truth-functional. Possibility is not a truth-functional concept; some falsehoods are possible; some falsehoods are impossible. Thus, possibility cannot be analysed in truth-functional logic.
Either it's true that the minister won't listen anyway, or it's true they will listen in any case, or it's true that they might or might not listen. Those are distinct situations. Just leaving our any statement is a weaker claim than just saying it's unsure. It's the same as "we have a chance at convincing" also being a possibility.
Truth table:



possible the minister wont listen
have to try
true




no
no
no


no
yes
no


yes
no
no


yes
yes
yes




P and Q




how can I better approach my professor when dealing with these questions?

Write down a truth table, to see which conditions express the same as natural language, get an agreement about the last column of the truth table.

I disagree for the first part : It's possible that the protest in Utrecth does not convince the gouvernment -> !(Q->P). "Only If" mean it's necessary, not sufficient.

The question posits "P: it is possible..." Not necessary. That choice of P was the OPs choice, not mine. This implies possible but not a sure convincing of the Utrecht government.

'Only if' is not a biconditional.

In natural language it is not. But in this case the whole sentence indicates that the protest would be both necessary and sufficient to generate a chance.

I don't like the comma in the original sentence. I think it makes the whole thing ambiguous between "only if" or "if and only if". But some people litter commas around whenever they think they have too many words in a row, so I'm not convinced what can be deduced from it. The original sentence certainly doesn't explicitly rule out that there is some other, unstated "only if". This is where philosophy meets contract law. A lawyer might argue that given an interpretation where the comma makes no difference, and one where it does, then since it's there we should assume it's needed.

@SteveJessop I like the answer (and the bonus exercise!) you have posted, but here, I am unable to see how the comma in the original sentence introduces ambiguity. No matter how much I roll it around in my head, I do not see how removing the comma results in a sentence which explicitly rules out there being additional, unstated 'only ifs'.

@sdenham: I meant that without the comma, "X only if Y" unambiguously means "X -> Y". With the comma, I think there's a possible ambiguity since "X, only if Y" could for example be intended as meaning "X (but only if Y)", that is to say "X, unless -Y, in which case -X". Which is "X if and only if Y". But the whole issue of authorial intent, and for that matter the post-modern backlash and death of the author, is not really an L1 logic kind of discussion, so I'm not sure how far we're really supposed to be splitting hairs in trying to solve these exercises :-)

Tbh I think another valid lesson the questioner might learn here is that mathematicians, and by extension anyone trying to do symbolic formal logic, are not guaranteed to survive contact with the actual English language! Speaking as a mathematics graduate, the philosophers are welcome to take over when it comes to meaning. And even they might need to defer if a professional linguist shows up ;-)

And, although it tends to leave you vulnerable to trick questions, there's a legit strategy in solving assignment exercises which goes, "this is a simple exercise, so assume I don't have to do anything clever, solve it, and if necessary prove any preconditions I've skipped over once I know the answer". I doubt this first-week exercise in propositional calculus was really intended to test the students' interpretation of an arguably-ambiguous comma, so do the opposite of the lawyers and ignore the comma. Or give both answers, if you're lucky enough to have your assignments marked by a human.

... when the question is supposed to be difficult, usually you can tell from the way it's phrased: "carefully prove"; "10 marks"; "if time allows"; "you may not use the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem without proof"; and whatnot.

The truth table is what matters. If any two people disagree on the L1 form, they necessarily disagree on some row in the truth table (or the choice of x and y), and each row can be discussed in isolation. Only when that disagreement is voiced can we analyze whether the original sentence implies one or the other result in the truth table.

@SteveJessop Thank you for your reply. Personally, I'm not convinced that the comma-free statement unambiguously means "X -> Y", basically on account of the points you make in the rest of your reply, and also because it seems to me that in ordinary usage, vacuous truths are regarded as improper or out-of-scope in some sense. I take your point that, in discussing personagem's situation, these concerns should be put aside - but that seems to raise the question of whether, given that these issues are apparent in the bigger picture, classroom exercises like these risk confusing the students.

@sdenham: maybe it's my background, but honestly I don't even say "only if" except when I mean a necessary but not sufficient condition. What actual human being said, "We have a chance at convincing the government not to cut higher education, only if we protest in Utrecht on November 14th."? I would struggle even to read that aloud without inserting "but" after the comma. I might say "We only have a chance at convincing the government not to cut higher education, if we protest at Utrecht on November 14th". It's barely real English, but it can be syntactically analysed.

... although thinking more about that, actually I do use "but only if" to mean "if and only if", in conversation, not just as part of a logic puzzle. "You can have a cookie but only if you finish your salad" is a biconditional, whereas "You can have a cookie only if you finish your salad" to me is a verbal trap to make someone eat their salad and then rob them of their cookie. So, I don't say "only if" on its own unless I really mean that tortuous necessary-but-perhaps-not-sufficient.

Regarding your answers:
I think the first one is correct, but you could do slightly better with the second one.

From the logical perspective, the formulas p => q and ~q => ~p are equivalent. They are also reasonably similar in structure to the original sentence. I don't believe there are any reasons to prefer one over the other.

You are right that possibility has no logical value, but this relates to the whole sentence just as much as its first part. Using this argument consequently we would be forced to conclude that the sentence can not be translated at all. I believe the translation is possible to some extent: although "and" doesn't fully capture the meaning of "but", it is still the closest that we can get. For this reason I think your professor was right in this case.


Having said that, let me emphasize my main point here:
There is no objectively correct way to translate these English sentences into formal logic.
Sentences in natural language convey certain meanings and flavours that the language of logic was never meant to capture. As you point out: logical connectives should connect sentences that are objectively true or false, but "we have to try" is neither true nor false, it only expresses a resolute intention. Also the conjunction doesn't capture the meaning of "but" faithfully.
The problem formulation itself hints at this issue:

Formalize the following sentences into sentences of L1 with as much detail as possible. Note any difficulties that arise.

It is probably the intention behind the problem to exhibit the limitations of formal logic. There is a certain amount of meaning that is possible to translate, and I think you did that reasonably well, but anything beyond is a matter of taste and impression.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
